# jQuery: not() in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have simple jQuery code but I can't anywhere find how I can write not() from jQuery in new Javascript.

Is there any option how to do this?

**MY CODE:**

```
$('.chevron').click(function() {

    var $ptag = $(this).closest('.column').find('p');
    $('.chevron.active').not(this).removeClass('active');
    $('p.active').not($ptag).removeClass('active');

    $(this).toggleClass('active');
    $ptag.toggleClass('active');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

There's no built-in shortcut, you'll have to iterate over the collection and remove the item that matches the clicked `.chevron`, or one of its associated `<p>`s:

```
const chevrons = [...document.querySelectorAll('.chevron.active')];
const chevronsNotThis = chevrons.filter(chev => chev !== this);
```

```
const thesePs = [...this.closest('.column').querySelectorAll('p')];
const activePs = [...document.querySelectorAll('p.active')];
const activePsNotThis = activePs.filter(activeP => !thesePs.includes(activeP));
```

Comment: Note: this will only work in ES6.The spread operator can be replaced in ES5 with the following: https://github.com/reduxjs/redux/issues/733#issuecomment-140427423